# How should I write chord diagrams in text form, if they use two digit fret numbers?

Tags: chords

I'm used to notating chords in text form, such as E major being 022100 or A major being x02220, but what happens when you are using two-digit frets?

For example, in DADGBE tuning you can play A and Dm on the 9th and 10th frets:

[image]

Here, I have to use the fret numbers 10 to 12. How do I do this?

Comment: So what's wrong with A major being 002220?! Why not put a hyphen between string/fret nos?

Comment: @Tim if I wanted 002220 I'd write A/E

Answer (score 2):

I guess this notation simply doesn't work. You could be creative and do slight modifications, for example: X-0-11-9-10-12,  X0(11)9(10)(12), X/0/11/9/10/12. I guess all these would be universally understandable in the context. I've never seen a standard notation in this case.

Comment: one more option would just be spaces: x 0 11 9 10 12.  above options are also good. just be consistent.

Comment: @b3ko the problem would be how to separate one chord from another maybe?

Comment: ah yeah, good point. i guess it depends on the overall structure. will this be part of a lead sheet, or just by itself, unclear.